# Opening files based on variable file name VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I have three different variables x,y & Z storing different names. and I have to open a file based on the format x_y_z.xls

```
dim x,y,z as string
x= abc
y= def
z= ece  
Const strfolder As String = "C:\Users\source\"
Const samepattern As String = "x_y_Z.xls"
samefiletype = Dir(strfolder & samepattern, vbNormal)
workbooks.open(samefiletye)
```

for some reason I have to save the file name in a temp variables x,y & z and pass it on to open the file based on the variable name. I'm not able to open files based on variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't const be always constant? You are trying to assing variable to constant. Maybe declare it also as variable.

```
dim x,y,z, strfolder, samepattern as string
x= abc
y= def
z= ece  
strfolder = "C:\Users\source\"
samepattern = x & "_" & y &"_" & Z & ".xls"
samefiletype = Dir(strfolder & samepattern, vbNormal)
workbooks.open(samefiletye)
```

Comment: You can improve this answer by using `Dim x As String, y As String, z As String, strfolder As String, samepattern As String` - not declaring the type of your variable may often be considered a sub-optimal practice.

Comment: So all variables separeted by comma like (variable 1, variable2, .....,variable n as string) is refering to type mentioned at end but good practice says that we should declare each one separetly?

Comment: Hi, no, if you have `Dim x, y, z As String` then only `z` is a `String` and `x` and `y` will be `Variant` type. Probably not a problem if you are only doing stuff with `String`s but with different variable types, it can often be a source of ambiuguity.

Comment: Hi . Have changed constant as string and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change the code below.

```
dim x,y,z as string
x= "abc"
y= "def"
z= "ece" 
Const strfolder As String = "C:\Users\source\"
Const samepattern As String = x & "_" & y &"_" & Z & ".xls"
samefiletype = Dir(strfolder & samepattern, vbNormal)
workbooks.open(samefiletye)
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im getting error Constant expression required. How do I get rid of it.

Comment: have changed the ans a little , sorry for that miss.